# Unable to import PIL with Pillow installed - Django project under venv

Tags: python, django, import, python-imaging-library

I've been struggling for hours trying to debug this and none of the solutions I've found worked for me.

I have a Django project running in a virtual env and installed Pillow to use Image.
The problem is that I can't import it. VScode tells me that it is "Unable to import 'PIL'"

I have other packages like crispy_forms that are installed and work perfectly fine.

If I open the Python shell using `py manage.py shell` then run `from PIL import Image` I get no errors.

Furthermore if I now type `Image` It returns the correct infos : `<module 'PIL.Image' from 'C:\\Users\\XXXX\\Documents\\webDev\\djangoProjects\\env\\lib\\site-packages\\pillow-7.2.0-py3.8-win32.egg\\PIL\\Image.py'>`

I tried to uninstall Pillow then reinstall it, even using `easy_install Pillow`.

This is clearly not a problem of pathing or different versions of Python as I'm in my virtual env AND
as show above I can run the import on my shell and find the files.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: *VScode tells me that it is "Unable to import 'PIL'"* - seems like your VSCode is not configured to use the virtualenv. Please provide the whole traceback and eventually a proof it's (not) using the virtualenv to determine the issue further.

Comment: Full traceback is "Unable to import 'PIL'  pylint (import-error)". I have not configured VScode to use the venv but so far everything worked perfectly well. I'm gonna check about this. Thanks

Comment: works perfectly well until it doesn't.

Comment: You were spot on ! It was exactly the problem. VScode was linked to the wrong Python interpreter. Solved it using VScode DOCS : https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments
Thanks for your help.